# Force app to wait to send a new text message

Tags: java, android, exception, sleep, wait

I've got a pretty simple app I'm trying to make. What I want to do is have an app that can send multiple texts to 1 or more recipients. I have accomplished this, but it doesn't seem to send the full number of texts.

I assume the problem is that the texts are being sent to rapidly. I'm trying to just make the program wait a second, but when I just type in "Thread.sleep(1000);" I get an error saying there is an unhandled exception in Eclipse. Is there a way around this? Do I really need to do a try/catch for these few lines of code? If I do need a try/catch, what's the best way to write it for this app?

Also, as a note I be allowing the sleep time to be customized in a later version, so please keep that in mind with your responses.

```
Integer i = 0;
while (i < numTextSend)
{
        sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
}
```

[EDIT] Updated Code:

```
final Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //Grab values from UI
            String number = String.valueOf(mNumber.getText().toString());
            Integer numTextSend = Integer.parseInt(mNumTextSend.getText().toString());
            String message = String.valueOf(mMessage.getText().toString());

            //Send SMS message(s)
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            Integer i = 0;
            while (i < numTextSend)
            {
                sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
                //Make App wait 1 second
                i++;
            }
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed()` of **handler** to execute any task at a delay

**Sample code**

```
    Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(null, null, null, null,
                null);
    }
};
h.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm just not sure how to implement this into my code currently. I'm updated my question with more code.

Comment: Is the 'h.postDelayed(r, 1000);' supposed to be in there twice?

Comment: Alright. I thought that looked a little odd. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As per the javaDoc [sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) method throws [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) so you will ideally need to either surround it with a try/catch block.

For customizing the SleepTime you can always declare it in some class (AppConstants.java) or else can always keep in in strings.xml and read it from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use a try catch, what do you think is the best way to write it given the code I have above?